# GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP - Generating a grid for a single draw call (degenerate triangles)

Tags: opengl-es, indexing, vertex

I need to create a grid ready for GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP rendering.

My **grid** is just a :

- Position ( self explanatory )
- Size ( the x,y size )
- Resolution ( the spacing between each vertex in x,y )

Here is the method used to create verts/indices and return them:

```
int iCols = vSize.x / vResolution.x;
int iRows = vSize.y / vResolution.y;


// Create Vertices
for(int y = 0; y < iRows; y ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < iCols; x ++)
    {
        float startu  = (float)x / (float)vSize.x;
        float startv  = (float)y / (float)vSize.y; 


        tControlVertex.Color    = vColor;
        tControlVertex.Position = CVector3(x * vResolution.x,y * vResolution.y,0);
        tControlVertex.TexCoord = CVector2(startu, startv - 1.0 );

        vMeshVertices.push_back(tControlVertex);   
    }
}


// Create Indices
rIndices.clear();

for (int r = 0; r < iRows - 1; r++)
{
    rIndices.push_back(r*iCols);

    for (int c = 0; c < iCols; c++)
    {
        rIndices.push_back(r*iCols+c);
        rIndices.push_back((r+1)*iCols+c);
    }
    rIndices.push_back((r + 1) * iCols + (iCols - 1));
}
```

And to visualise that, few examples first.

1) Size 512x512 Resolution 64x64, so it should be made of 8 x 8 quads, but i get 7x7 only

[image: 512x512 Grid / 64x64 = 7x7 instead of 8x8 ?]

2) Size 512x512 Resolution 128x128, so it should be made of 4 x 4 quads, but i get 3x3 only

[image]

3) Size 128x128 Resolution 8x8 so it should be made of 16 x 16 quads but i get 15x15 only

[image]

So as you can see, i am missing the Last Row and Last Column somewhere.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have solved this,
see :

[GameDev StackExchange][1]


  [1]: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48104/opengl-gl-triangle-strip-creating-grid-with-degenerate-triangles-for-one-draw/48118#48118

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: make your for-loop test `<=`, as compared to just `<`, when you're generating your vertices and indices.

The issue is that the computation of your `iRows` and `iCols` variables is counting the number of primitives of a particular resolution for a range of pixels; call that *n*.  For a triangle strip of *n* primtives, you need *n+2* primitives, so you're just missing the last "row" and "column" of vertices.

The index generation loop needs to be:

```
for ( int r = 0; r <= iRows; ++r ) {
    for ( int c = 0; c <= iCols; ++c ) {
        rIndices.push_back( c + r + r*iCols );
        rIndices.push_back( c + r + (r+1)*iCols + 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: If that would be so easy, but it is not.

Have a look what happens when i go with "<=" instead of "<" in the code.

http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/7e64a67f.png

When <= is applied to indices, all is messed up.


http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/c8269b3d.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're computing the vertex positions correctly (you can test this by rendering using GL_POINTS), but your index computations seem suspect.  I believe the code I added in the edit to the answer will generate the correct indices, assuming you render each tristrip separately (i.e., you pass _2*(iRows+1)_ in your `glDrawElements` call)

Comment: thanks Radical7, but i need to handle this grid with one draw call by stiching the triangles / using degenerate triangles..